# Работа конструктора копирования в C++

Tags: c++

разбираю конструкторы копирования. Везде сказано, что конструктор копирования вызывается в том числе при инициализации и при возвращении объекта из функции.

При возврате объекта мол объект копируется во временную переменную и пошло поехало.

Код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test{
    int a, b;
public:
    Test(int i, int j){
        a = i; b = j;
    }
    ~Test(){
        cout << "Remove Test. b: " << b << "\n"; 
    }

    Test(const Test &test){
        cout << "Copying ..." << "\n";
        a = test.a;
        b = test.b + 1;
    }
};

Test cringe();


int main(){
    Test test(1, 1);
    cout << "no cringe" << "\n";
    Test test2 = cringe(); //Здесь конструктор не работает, а должен сработать дважды (Test test2(cringe) тоже не работает)
    cout << "after cringe" << "\n";

    Test test1 = test; //Здесь конструктор работает
    return 0;
}


Test cringe(){
    Test test(1, 10);
    cout << "[cringe]: Out" << "\n";

    return test;
}
```

Вывод программы:

```
no cringe
[cringe]: Out
after cringe
Copying ...
Remove Test. b: 2
Remove Test. b: 10
Remove Test. b: 1
```

Конструктор не срабатывает при выходе из функции cringe() и не срабатывает при инициализации объекта test2.

Помогите, почему?

Comment: Потому что так положено по стандарту C++17... См. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Answer (score -1):

Потому что так положено по стандарту C++17... См. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Огромное спасибо Harry.